# FRAMESET to IFRAMES

Tags: html, frames

I'm trying to convert some old code that uses FRAMESET to use IFRAMEs . The old code results in two horizontal frames.

```
<frameset rows="400,250" cols="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="yes" border="1">
<frame name="up" src="up.php" scrolling="yes" id="topFrame"  >
<frame name="below" scrolling="yes" target="main" id="belowFrame" src="below.php" >
```

how to do that suing iframes please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to achieve this by applying `position:fixed` to two separate iframes.

**Working Example:**

```css
iframe {
display: block;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
border: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
width: 100%;
}

#topFrame {
top: 0;
height: 400px;
}

#bottomFrame {
top: 401px;
height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="topFrame" src="">
<iframe id="bottomFrame"src="" >
```